# Zend_Json_Server: Return error with custom message and code?

Tags: php, json, zend-framework, rpc

I have an API that uses Zend_Json_Server and defines a class that handles the requests.
However, how can I return an error, so that I can set the message AND the error code?
When I throw a new exception, I can only set the message. The exception code is not used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution:

The error code has to be somewhere between -32099 and -32000.

So you can throw an Exception and pass one of those valid error codes.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you call the [fault method](http://files.zend.com/help/Zend-Framework/zend.json.server.html#zend.json.server.details.zendjsonserver) on Zend_Json_Server?

Comment: How should I do that from within my class? I have no instance of the Zend_Json_Server anywhere in my class that is getting mapped.